# Where is the config. problem in this Firebase and React App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, function

App is based on 2-year old tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82tZAPMHfT4
Since the tutorial is over 2 years old, I've made config changes that diverge from what is brought up in the tutorial, but I don't seem to be making any headway.

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "functions",
   "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
   "scripts": {
      "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
      "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
      "start": "npm run shell",
      "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
      "logs": "firebase functions:log",
      "webpack": "node_modules/.bin/webpack -d"
   },
   "engines": {
      "node": "8"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
      "consolidate": "^0.15.1",
      "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "firebase": "^7.5.0",
      "handlebars": "^4.5.3",
      "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
      "react": "^16.12.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
      "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
      "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
      "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
      "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "braces": "^3.0.2",
      "firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
      "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
      "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
      "firebase-tools": "^7.9.0",
      "webpack": "^4.41.2",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
   },
   "private": true
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let path = require("path");

let config = {
   entry: "./index.js",
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js?/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
               presets: ["@babel/react"],
            },
         },
      ],
   },
   output: {
      filename: "bundle.js",
      path: __dirname + "/public",
   },
};

module.exports = config;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
   "compact": false
}
```

**After running npm run webpack, lots of errors of the form:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/protos/protos.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/tm/devDir/fbHosting/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/protos/protos.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (2:10)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "nested": {
    |           ^
  3 |     "google": {
  4 |       "nested": {
  5 |         "firestore": {
```

**And/or:**

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client_config.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/tm/devDir/fbHosting/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client_config.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (2:14)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "interfaces": {
    |               ^
  3 |     "google.firestore.admin.v1.FirestoreAdmin": {
  4 |       "retry_codes": {
  5 |         "idempotent": [
```

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading I think its still looking for old semi colon format configuration.

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact

npm install -g firebase-tools
```

this is wrong 
/Users/tm/devDir/fbHosting/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client_config.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (2:14)
try

```
npm install @google-cloud/firestore

Version
2.6.1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jin Thakur. I took your advice and updated the dependencies you called out plus all the other dependencies. The only package version that changed was **"@babel/core": "^7.7.5"** (went from **^7.0.0 to ^7.7.5**). Still the same errors as before after running npm run webpack.

Comment: check why it is trying to build https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore take 2.8 version    npm install @google-cloud/firestore